# why the following code gives the first mobile no. irrespective of name

Tags: c, string, switch-statement, comparison

Please explain why the following code gives the first mobile no. irrespective of entered name:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int mobileno(char[]);

int main(){

 char input[20];
 gets(input); 
 printf("%s",input);          
 int x;
 x = mobileno(input);  
printf("%d",x);
switch(x){
          case 0:printf("7255222319");break;
          case 1:printf("9404521113");break;
          case 2:printf("9326513553");break;
          case 3:printf("9845621611");break;
          case 4:printf("4556312390");break;
          case 5:printf("9245178190");break;
          case 6:printf("9214188214");break;
          case 7:printf("7014773244");break;
          case 8:printf("7898888044");break; 

          };    

    getch(); 
    return 0;
}

int mobileno(char s[20]){


    if( s="katrina" )
    {return 1;}else{
    if( s="shahid" ){return 2;}else{
    if( s="ranbir" ){return 3;}else{
    if( s="sharukh" ){return 4;}else{
    if( s="hema" ){return 5;}else{
    if( s="amitabh" ){return 6;}else{
    if( s="shashnk" ){return 7;}else{
    if( s="raj" ){return 8;}else{
    if( s="aishwarya" ){return 0;}else{

        return 9;}}}}}}}}};

    };
```

Comment: you should not use = for string comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot **compare** *strings* using `=` (or even by `==`, for that matter) operator. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for that.

In your code, inside `mobileno()` function,

```
if( s="katrina" )
```

is *essentially* trying to *assign* the base address of the *string* literal `"katrina"` to `s`. It is nowhere near a *comparison*.

That said,

1. Never use `gets()`, it suffer from buffer overflow problem. Use the safer alternative, [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. Recommended signature of `main()`  is `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

this code

```
if( s="katrina" )
```

assigns "katrina" to s and the result is not 0, i.e. "true". To compare, use strcmp instead. While you can compare values with "==", don't use it for strings as it would only compare the address, and two identical strings could still have different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
int mobileno(char s[20]){


    if( s="katrina" )
    {return 1;}else{
    if( s="shahid" ){return 2;}else{
    if( s="ranbir" ){return 3;}else{
    if( s="sharukh" ){return 4;}else{
    if( s="hema" ){return 5;}else{
    if( s="amitabh" ){return 6;}else{
    if( s="shashnk" ){return 7;}else{
    if( s="raj" ){return 8;}else{
    if( s="aishwarya" ){return 0;}else{

        return 9;}}}}}}}}};

    };
```

there is used the assignment operator `=` that assigns the address of the first characters of string literals in if conditions. For example in thsi statement

```
    if( s="katrina" )
```

pointer s is assigned to the address of the first character of string literal "katrina" that is evidently is not equal to NULL. So the condition is alway true.:)

If you want to compare to strings you should use standard C function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>`

Rewrite the function the following way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int mobileno( const char *s )
{
    const char *name[] = 
    {
        "aishwarya", "katrina", "shahid", "ranbir", "sharukh",
        "hema", "amitabh", "shashnk", "raj"
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( name ) / sizeof( *name );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N && strcmp( s, name[i] ) != 0 ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

Take into account that function `gets` is not a C Standard function any more because it is unsafe. Use instead function `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your `if` conditions:

```
if( s="katrina" )
```

**Assignment instead of equality** :

`a=b` means assigning the value of `b` to `a`.

`a==b'` means checking if both `a` and `b` have same values.

**Char array comparison**: Use strcmp() instead:

```
 if( strcmp(s,"katrina")==0 )
```